# Why is fractional part not discarded in python in some cases

Tags: python, floor-division

In python
`3//2` evaluates to `1`, in this case, the fractional part is discarded
while `1.2//1` evaluates to `1.0`

Comment: 1.2 is a floating data type...

Comment: If one of the operand is float, the result will be float. [Check Here](https://www.learndatasci.com/solutions/python-double-slash-operator-floor-division/#:~:text=In%20Python%2C%20we%20can%20perform,it%20equivalent%20to%20the%20math.)

Comment: From https://peps.python.org/pep-0238/ : 'The current division (/) operator has an ambiguous meaning for numerical arguments: it returns the floor of the mathematical result of division if the arguments are ints or longs, but it returns a reasonable approximation of the division result if the arguments are floats or complex.'

Comment: That's more to do with the rationale for adding `//` than about the definition of `float.__floordiv__`.

Comment: "A new operator, //, is the floor division operator. (Yes, we know it looks like C++’s comment symbol.) // always performs floor division no matter what the types of its operands are, so 1 // 2 is 0 and 1.0 // 2.0 is also 0.0." https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.2.html?highlight=integer%20division#:~:text=changes%202.2%20introduces%3A-,A%20new%20operator%2C%20//,-%2C%20is%20the%20floor

Comment: `1.0` doesn't have a fractional part, either. It's a `float` value corresponding to the largest integer less than `1.2 / 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The `//` operator performs floor division and will return the largest multiple of the divisor that is les than or equal to the dividend.

E.g. `3 // 2` will return `1` because `3` divided by `2` is `1.5` and the  fractional part is cut off.

On the other hand `1.2 // 1` will return `1.0` because `1.2` divided by `1` is `1.2`, and the result is not an integer. In this case the `//` operator would return a float number with the fractional part preserved.

Note: the `//` operator has different behavior depending on the types of the operands. If both operands are integers, the result is an integer. If one operand is a floating-point number, the result is a floating-point number.

E.g.

```
>>> 3.0 // 2
1.0
>>> 3 // 2.0
1.0
>>> 4 // 2.0
2.0
>>> 4 // 2
2
```